# Throwing dice and finding limits

Tags: probability, limits, dice, central-limit-theorem

We throw an fair dice $n$ times. Let $S_n$ be the number of throws with even number of dots on the dice.

1.) Calculate the limit
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(2S_n \leq n)$$

2.) Express the value of the limit
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(2S_n \leq n + \sqrt{n})$$
as a definite integral of suitable function.

First  can we say
$$S_n = X_1+X_2+...+X_n$$
$$X_1+X_2+...+X_n  \sim \mathrm{Geo}( \frac{1}{2} )$$

I know that probability of having even dots show up on the dice is $\frac{1}{2}$. So if we throw the dice $n$ times does that mean that the limit of $S_n$ will converge toward $\frac{n}{2}$? And if so can we than say

$$S_n = \frac{n}{2}$$
$$ n = 2S_n$$

I’m not very good at solving this type of exercise so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know of any dice that tell lies, so I guess all my dice are honest? =P

Comment: @user21820 Presumably *fair* and not *honest* - apparently translating such terms using a generic dictionary doesn't always yield the best result. :)

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: Yea I know; it was just a joke. =)

Comment: Sorry guys, I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

A sum of independent bernoulli random variables (which you've noted each have probability $\frac12$) will be a binomial random variable, but in this case more importantly the resulting sum's cumulative distribution function will tend to that of the normal distribution with the same mean and variance, by the central limit theorem. That should answer both questions simultaneously.

Comment: Can you show me any of the steps for question 1.) or 2.) ?

Comment: @nisdex: Hmm a key issue that you might be missing is the mean and variance of a sum of random variables. $E(X+Y) = E(X)+E(Y)$ for any r.v. $X,Y$, which gives you the mean that you guessed. $Var(X+Y) = Var(X)+Var(Y)$ for any independent r.v. $X,Y$, which allows you to compute $Var(\sum_{k=1}^n X_k)$ (by induction). Now central limit theorem gives $P( \frac{S_n-E(S_n)}{\sqrt{Var(S_n)}} \le x ) \to P( N(0,1) \le x )$ as $n \to \infty$, because $Var(S_n)$ exists and is finite.